# Object does not move in random position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can’t understand what the problem is, the “text” in the inspector added.
It should work but according to the "bad code" nothing works.

```
public Text hy;
private void Start()
{
    float posX = hy.transform.position.x;
    float posY = hy.transform.position.y;
    posX = Random.Range(-400f,400f);
    posY = Random.Range(-400f, 400f);
}
```

Comment: "bad code"? "Should work"? What do you mean? What does not work? What do you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: This is a joke of developers from Russia, when something does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`posX` and `posY` are simply local variables that hold a value.

By assigning a new value to `posX` and `posY` you only store the values in your local variables but never assign it back to the objects position.

If you do

```
float posX = hy.transform.position.x;
```

and then

```
posX = Random.Range(-400f,400f);
```

you only store a new value in `posX` ... it is a `float` and in no way "linked" to the `hy.transform.position.x` so they are not automatically synchronized.

It only copies the value if you want so.

You have to actually assign a new vector to the `hy.transform.position` in order to move it! What you want to do is

```
private void Start()
{
    float posX = Random.Range(-400f, 400f);
    float posY = Random.Range(-400f, 400f);

    hy.transform.position = new Vector3(posX, posY);
}
```